# Correlation significance values change depending on number of variables tested in Genstat

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, genstat

I'm doing some exploratory data analysis in Genstat, and tried running correlations relating a number of variables to my variable of interest (VOI). First, I just ran a subset of the variables, and got one set of results. Then I ran all the variables at once, to produce a heatmap correlation plot for visualisation. I noticed the correlation values and significance were different, so I then ran a few as individual correlations and got yet another set of outputs. Here's a table summarising the different outputs I got each time (just the significance levels to keep it simple):

[image: Table showing different p values obtained when running correlations in a long list, in a subset group, and individually]

I would have expected that the correlation values would be the same, no matter how many correlations I ran in one command. So I must be doing something silly/not understanding something really basic here. Has Genstat somehow tried to analyse relationships between the variables instead of just doing the correlation between VarA and VOI, then correlation between VarB and VOI, etc.?

The Genstat code is:

```
FCORRELATION [PRINT=correlations,test; METHOD=twosided] VOI,VarA, VarB, VarC
```

I've looked up the FCORRELATION procedure info on the Genstat website, but still don't understand why the values would be changing.

I can just run these all individually to get the results I am looking for, or move into another software (SPSS doesn't seem to have this problem and gives me the same outputs every time regardless of whether I run in groups, a long list at once, or individually), but I'd really like to understand why this is happening, so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you check whether missing values in one variable lead to the deletion of observations? This would affect all pairwise correlations

Comment: Thank you very much, that does seem to be the issue! This possibility didn't even occur to me, thanks for your help!